# How to pass link options to the PhoenixHTML link with this setup

Tags: html, elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm currently doing a partial template for any table with search fields. I need to generate passed from controller function names with options as links in my template.

I have already tried solution I pasted as `code` below. It doesn't work and I have no clue why.

**Controller**:

```
@table_links [{:show, []}, {:edit, []}, {:delete, [method: :delete, data: [confirmation: "Are you sure?"]]}]
```

This module attribute is assigned to `conn` and passed to the template.

**Rendering partial**:

```
<%= render BaseAppWeb.SharedView, "table_partial.html",
   Map.merge(assigns, 
    %{action: Routes.admin_users_path(@conn, :index), 
    opts: [method: :get], 
    columns: @searchable_columns,
    table_links: @table_links,
    links_path: &Routes.admin_users_path/3}) %>
```

**Partial links generation**:

```
<%= for {function, options} <- @table_links  do %>
            <%= case function do
              :show -> {:safe, "<i class = \"mdi mdi-magnify\">"}
              :edit -> {:safe, "<i class = \"mdi mdi-pencil\">"}
              :delete -> {:safe, "<i class = \"mdi mdi mdi-trash-can-outline\">"}
              _ -> {:safe, "<i class = \" mdi mdi-arrow-right-bold-circle-outline\">"}
            end%>
            <%= link(Atom.to_string(function) |> String.capitalize(), to: @links_path.(@conn, function, entity), options) %>
          <% end %>
```

Error that is showing up:

> lib/base_app_web/templates/shared/table_partial.html.eex:42: syntax error before: options

Without including `options`, as shown below, everything works fine, but I haven't got `method:` as link option, which is necessary in my case.

```
<%= link(Atom.to_string(function) |> String.capitalize(), to: @links_path.(@conn, function, entity)) %>
```

I'll really be grateful for any advice that will help me pass link options from controller to links in templates!

Edit:
Here is a `table_partial.html.eex` which you asked for:

```
<div class = "col-12">
<%= form_for @conn, @action, @opts, fn f -> %>
  <%= Enum.reduce @columns, [], fn {function, {key, value}}, acc -> %>
    <%= case function do
      :date_input -> [acc] ++ [
        build_form(f, {:label, {:from_date, "#{value} from"}}),
        build_form(f, {function, {:from_date, value}}), 
        build_form(f, {:label, {:from_date, "#{value} to"}}), 
        build_form(f, {function, {:to_date, value}})]
      _other -> [acc] ++ [build_form(f, {:label, {key, value}}), build_form(f, {function, {key, value}})]
      end %>
  <% end %>
  <%= submit "Search", name: "order_by", value: "" %>
<hr>

<div class = "row">
  <div class = "col-12">
  <table class = "table dt-responsive nowrap talbe-borderless table-hover">
    <thead class = "thead-light">
      <tr>
        <%= for {_function, {_key, value}} <- @searchable_columns  do %>
          <th><%= submit "#{value}", name: "order_by", value: "#{value}" %> </th>
        <% end %>
        <th>Options</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
<% end %>
    <tbody>
      <%= for entity <- @entities do %>
        <tr>
          <%= for {_function, {key, _value}} <- @searchable_columns  do %>
            <td><%= Map.get(entity, key) %></td>
          <% end %>
          <td>
          <%= for {function, options} <- @table_links  do %>
            <%= case function do
              :show -> {:safe, "<i class = \"mdi mdi-magnify\">"}
              :edit -> {:safe, "<i class = \"mdi mdi-pencil\">"}
              :delete -> {:safe, "<i class = \"mdi mdi mdi-trash-can-outline\">"}
              _ -> {:safe, "<i class = \" mdi mdi-arrow-right-bold-circle-outline\">"}
            end%>
            <%= link(Atom.to_string(function) |> String.capitalize(), to: @links_path.(@conn, function, entity), options) %>
          <% end %>
          </td>
        </tr>
      <% end %>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

I can't build them normally, because I'm building multiple different tables with this template and different tables `Options` may vary.

Comment: Can you show the entire table_partial.html.eex file? I am unable to recreate your issue. Also, why are you doing this with your links? Why not just build the links normally instead of iterating over a list?

Comment: Yeah, sure - I pasted it in `Edit`. I also wrote a clarification - I can't build them normally, because I'm building multiple different tables with this template and different tables Options may vary.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, if someone will look for something like this in the future - here is solution I just found to pass arguments:

**Controller:**

```
  @table_links [{:show, %{:method => :get, :data => []}}, {:edit, %{:method => :get, :data => []}}, {:delete, %{:method => :delete, :data => [confirm: "Are you sure?"]}}]
```

**table_partial.html.eex**

```
<td>
<%= for {function, %{:method => method, :data => data}} <- @table_links  do %>
 <%= case function do
  :show -> {:safe, "<i class = \"mdi mdi-magnify\">"}
  :edit -> {:safe, "<i class = \"mdi mdi-pencil\">"}
  :delete -> {:safe, "<i class = \"mdi mdi mdi-trash-can-outline\">"}
  _ -> {:safe, "<i class = \" mdi mdi-arrow-right-bold-circle-outline\">"}
 end%>
 <%= link(Atom.to_string(function) |> String.capitalize(), to: @links_path.(@conn, function, entity), method: method, data: data) %>
<% end %>
</td>
```

That was pretty easy, <s>however confirmation still does not work</s>. It was because it is `confirm:`, not `confirmation:` - working good now :)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are trying to pass `options` into a keyword list. You will want to merge the lists in one of two ways. You can either do

```
Keyword.merge([to: @links_path.(@conn, function, entity)], options)
```

or

```
[to: @links_path.(@conn, function, entity)] ++ options
```

in

```
<%= link(Atom.to_string(function) |> String.capitalize(), to: @links_path.(@conn, function, entity), options) %>
```